# sitecore workflow is not resetting after change applied

Tags: sitecore, sitecore6, sitecore-workflow

Something i've noticed after installing a custom workflow is that items go over the workflow only when they are created for first time. After they reach the final state, further modifications of the item are not sending it back to "Draft". Any idea about what i might be overlooking? Do i need something special to the save events?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Are you making changes as an Administrator?  Those do not go through workflow.

Comment: hmm, however i noticed that created objects by me still go through the workflow?

Comment: Yep. At least, that's how my system works... but I've got all sorts of custom code running in mine, so couldn't say for certain that that is the correct behavior.  But seems reasonable.

Comment: From my experience it seems that newly created items will start off in the initial workflow state that is defined for that item - however edits made by administrators bypass workflow. That said as an Administrator you can manually change the workflow state to any state you wish. In generally you should run a separate non administrator account for content editing.